# Android Studio Manual Installation of System Images

Tags: android-studio

I have downloaded two system images for Android Studio from this site:
http://downloads.puresoftware.org/files/android

I need to know how to "*manually*" install these images, so that Android Studio can use them.

I am using Linux (Korora 22, which is based on Fedora).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there a question? because you said: `I need to know how to "manually" install these images` what do you need?

Comment: The question is how to manually install system images? Not using the SDK Manager.

Comment: install on what ? avd ?

Comment: Install on hard drive for AS to use them.
The system images can be installed by SDK Manager from inside AS. However, I opted to manually download them without using the SDK Manager.
So, now I have the files for the system images. Where is their proper location so that AS can access and use them?

Comment: tnx for your explanation:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System images` is using for `Emulators Image` and in windows you should paste it in something like this:

with this folder name in `sdk manager` PATH: `system-images`

another Operation systems you need to do something like above but with some difference in path and etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try it on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

download latest android studio from official site
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
There is also instruction manual for installation android studio in Linux os

and download your system image and past in your sdk folder.

Comment: I have already downloaded the latest version of Android Studio. Then **manually** downloaded the system images, outside of AS.
Now, I do not know how to manually install those system images. I do not want o use the SDK Manager for this.

Comment: you won't need it, follow my answer and find that path which you installed your sdk manager and then paste it and setup with avd and go.

Comment: @AndroidDev Thank you so much.